# Cannot use transactions in RavenDB 3 unittests

Tags: testing, transactions, nunit, ravendb, nosql

We have a couple of tests that relies on transactions to work. We are trying to move from RavenDB 2.5 to 3.0 now and in doing so all tests using transactions started to fail. We are using NUnit as our test framework.

I wrote a small example of the error we are getting:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TransactionTest : RavenTestBase
{
    [Test]
    public void TransactionTest1()
    {
        using (var store = NewDocumentStore(configureStore: ConfigureTestStore))
        {
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    session.Store(new SampleData { Id = "RavenDB" });
                    session.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ConfigureTestStore(EmbeddableDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        documentStore.RunInMemory = true;
        documentStore.Configuration.RunInUnreliableYetFastModeThatIsNotSuitableForProduction = true;
        documentStore.EnlistInDistributedTransactions = true;
    }
}
public class SampleData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

This results in the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The database <system> cannot be used with distributed transactions
```

I can set:

```
documentStore.EnlistInDistributedTransactions = false;
```

But then none of my transactions acctually works. The test above works fine in RavenDB 2.5. Is it not supposed to work in RavenDB 3 too?

Old version: 2.5.2874
New Version: 3.0.3690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question in https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=sv#!topic/ravendb/2fHg48KkuZM

And ayende answered it. The solution is to use esent to run the test and not voron.

I added this setting:

```
documentStore.Configuration.DefaultStorageTypeName = "esent";
```